# Two types of data, so two type of databases?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, nosql

For a social network site, I need to propose a DB. The application is written in Java & will be hosted on VPS(s) initially.

Broadly classified there is two type of data to be stored at backend:

```
 1. dynamic lists which are:

     - frequently appended to   
     - frequently read       
     - sometimes reduced    

 2. fixed set of data keyed by a primary key(sometimes modified).

 "For serving any page, I need to have access to both kind of data!"
```

As demanded by every other SN site, we need to consider for easy scaling in the future, but in addition to that our team & resources are also very very limited. We would like to start with a 1 or 2 medium sized VPS(s) & add more servers as data & load grows.

Personally I usually prefer something that is used by a large community, so ofcourse MySQL is big option but it doesn't fit our entire needs. It could be used for 2nd kind of data(*among the list above*) ie for storing fixed set of columns/data but not ideal for storing dynamic lists(ie 1st kind). 
**So should I use a 2nd database just to fit in only that type of data (two database each containing only data best suited for them)?** (Some suggested Cassandra to store the 2nd kind of data.)
 **What is the way to go ?**

Answer (score 1):

Use a traditional database when you need transactional integrity and you have a fixed set of relations to map.

Use a document database when you have multiple properties of objects to store in a flat structure; or where the schema (the properties of the objects) may change over time. This is one of the weaknesses of traditional database systems; changing schemas is possible but has lots of performance side-effects. In document databases, the properties of the object being stored have little impact on the overall performance of the system - and more practically the information stored about objects (their properties or "columns") can be modified without having to worry about schemas.

Use a key value store for ephemeral data.

From what you have described, I don't see any use case that would require a relational database.

Comment: I'm a relational database kind of girl and I agree with you, there seems to be little need for a relational database at all in this scenario.

Comment: iam wondering if document databases will scale (keep performance) on many clients (connections and querys) like traditional databases can..  MongoDB for example (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#how-does-mongodb-provide-concurrency) will lock if 1 client writes .. MySQL with innodb for example use record locking so this will scale better on high traffic websites even more if you use  the innodb facebook patch you feel the ironie in this... document database are more designed to handle fast analytic querys on a large set of data for a couple of clients..

Comment: @Burhan Khalid: Besides the above doubt, could you also clarify/add more to your answer giving a few suggestions/examples for each category of database

Comment: Don't worry about scale now; because scaling is a problem that has already been solved. Worry about finding the _right tool_ for the data you intend to store (and more importantly, for the queries you intend to write).

Comment: @HLGEM:  I don't know how my case is different than others but a lot of other SN sites also store the posts data in MySQL tables, & actually the 2nd kind of data (referred in the question) is posts data, users profile data etc. So why mysql is not suitable for me atleast for that data ?

Comment: I'm not saying you can't but that you don't need to because the other type of databases may work better. You certainly can put that data in a relationsional database, but should consider if there is anything that must be in a relational database.